# FTP Failed Transfers (Index page)

Tags: ftp

I am a web designer and have made updates to an index.html page for a client.  I am using the newest version of FileZilla.  I have tried uploading the newest version of this page from the local to the remote site.

Every time I try to complete this task I receive the following:

Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (64,148,130,80,12,243).
Command:    STOR index.html
Response:   550 index.html: Access is denied.

However, I AM able to upload other files to the server for example new images.
I have not made ANY configuration changes to the hosting account.

Any help/information would be great.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the login you are using isn't in the same group that the group that uploaded the original index.html file and so don't have the good permissions to do it.

For new files, it will no cause problems because you're the owner, but for the existing one, if you aren't in the same group and don't have the modification right, you will have this error.

Comment: Arnaud, I did take over the responsibilities for this web site recently but have made many changes to it over the past several months.  Would it matter at all that I am now using a different IP address to make the uploads?

Comment: No, IP doesn't enter into account here, if it was, you were blocked before (by not entering in the passive mode), but the STOR command was sent so you're sure that the data channel is open and all is fine (except right permissions). I'm sure of that because I recently developed the FTP protocol for the Compact Framework and manage this case ;)

Comment: So if I have not (at least knowingly) changed any of the FTP permissions, how would it make any sense that I can no longer make changes to that page?  I did recently change the FTP password, not sure if that could make a difference...

Comment: That's a very strange case... Are you sure to have the modification permissions ? (Normally you can see it in FileZilla)

Comment: I see that the permissions for that file are 555, but I did not change them to that level.  When I try and change to 777 I get this message:

Command: SITE CHMOD 777 index.html
Response: 500 'SITE CHMOD 777 index.html': command not understood

Comment: Try to change file permissions directly on the host machine (if you have access to it) or via your host file manager, I didn't see other solutions...